# How to bind a tab control header to to a tab control content?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I have a tab control with defined (as *Style* in *TabControl.ItemContainerStyle*) templates *HeaderTemplate* and *ContentTemplate*. Tab Control has no Items Source. Item Content has a custom User Control with a property *Status*. Item Header has a text block, where this status has to be displayed.
My question is how to bind this?

```
<TabControl x:Name="tbMain">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:Session x:Name="session"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="18" Height="18" Source="Resources/bullet_green.png"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1" Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding ?? session.Status}"/>
                            <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Grid.Column="2" Margin="1" Content="asdasd" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource CloseButton}" Click="btnDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Please post your (relevant) XAML markup.

Comment: did you try to bind with the 'ElementName' syntax ? Something like '<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1" Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding ElementName=session, Path=Status}"/>'

Comment: @Bruno Yes, I tried. It didn't work for me. The problem is, I think, that element *session* of the content template and the text block of the header template are in different scopes and are not visible to each other. That is exactly the question, how to access *session* element from this text block. I assume, it should be something like -> parent control (which is a single tab) -> content -> *session*, but I have no idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your custom control is receiving its data (`Status`) from a view model or something. Then rather than trying to bind from an element to another, maybe you can bind both `TextBlock` control to the same VM.

The following example works for me :

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace StackOverflow
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Status = "STATUS FROM VM";
    }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Session : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Status", typeof(string), typeof(Session), new PropertyMetadata("My Status"));

    static Session()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Session), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Session)));
    }

    public string Status
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StatusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StatusProperty, value); }
    }
}
}
```

And the XAML :

```
<TabControl x:Name="tbMain">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <stackOverflow:Session x:Name="session" Status="{Binding Status}">
                                <stackOverflow:Session.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="stackOverflow:Session">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}, Path=DataContext.Status}"></TextBlock>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </stackOverflow:Session.Template>
                            </stackOverflow:Session>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1" Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}, Path=DataContext.Status}"/>
                                <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Grid.Column="2" Margin="1" Content="asdasd" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TabItem></TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I like it, but it is a bit different from what I need. In may case *session* control has a socket client and I need to display a socket connection status in the header of tab. I need to avoid storing statuses in main window class. If I used this solution, I could just probably define an Items Source for the tab control and bind it. But the main window class is not supposed to have any information of sessions. Session just has a Status property, which has to be displayed in the header.